# GNU Make: Automatically Prerequisites can't work if rename header files

Tags: gnu-make

A common Makefile for automatically prereq, looks like:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)

$(OBJS): %.o: %.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

include $(DEPS)

$(DEPS): %.d: %.c
    xxx
```

the first time, build ok, the generated .d file like this:

```
config.o config.d: config.c config.h
```

then I rename config.h to config2.h, and modify config.c:

```
-#include "config.h"
+#include "config2.h"
```

make again, Makefile generate error:

> make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'config.h', needed by 'config.d'

because config.d depends config.h, How can I modify my Makefile to fix this rename problem.

Comment: You need a more advanced form of auto-dependency generation.  See for example: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: @MadScientist great article, solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple really. Your `.d` file needs this additional line:

```
config.h:
```

Now when *make* discovers `config.h` doesn't exist,
it will run the non-existent recipe and happily believe it has created `config.h`. Then it carries on.

The manual says:

> If a rule has no prerequisites or recipe, and the target of the rule is a nonexistent file, then make imagines this target to have been updated whenever its rule is run.

### How to we get this extra line?

Back in the day you would run a perl one-liner over the newly created `.d` file. Nowadays, for modern *gcc* variants, just add `-MP` to the compiler command-line.

> -MP This option instructs CPP to add a phony target for each dependency other than the main file, causing each to depend on nothing.  These dummy rules work around errors make gives if you remove header files without updating the Makefile to match.

Job's a good 'un.